# two same css classes on element should style differently

Tags: css

Is there a way to style same element based on the number of classes applied on it.
I have third party lib which renders td elements class 'off' and on some of the elements with class 'off','off'. I want style elements differently based on the number 'off' classes count on an element.

I tried this, but it applied display none for all elements.

```
td.off.off{
display:none;
}      
td.off{
cursor: none;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this totally makes sense. You are saying that the element is having the second .off added somehow, or that you are adding it yourself?

Comment: There's not such thing. `class="off off off"` is just `.off`. It doesn't make sense. Please add more info and code, including this third party lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many times you concatenate the **same** class name, the last definition will apply to *all* the elements with that class name (single or multiple times)

```css
div { background: #eee; margin: 10px; height: 30px; width: 100%; }

.off { background: blue; }

.off.off { background: red; }

.off.off.off { background: green; }
```

```html
<div class="off"></div>

<div class="off off"></div>  

<div class="off off off"></div>
```

So, no. You can not style `.off.off` any differently than `.off` based solely on the class name.